# Django | Al editar cualquier casilla de usuario, encripta el password encriptado, dejando el password original inservible

Tags: python, django

Al crear un usuario desde el panel de administrador se crea el usuario y el usuario accede sin problemas. El problema viene al editar cualquier casilla del usuario, ya que aunque no se modifique el password, toma el password encriptado como nuevo password y lo vuelve a encriptar lo encriptado, dejando sin acceso al usuario con password original. ¿Qué sucede?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**users > models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin
from .managers import UserManager

class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

    GENDER_CHOICES = (
        ('M','Masculino'),
        ('F','Femenino'),
        ('O','Otros'),
    )
    username = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER_CHOICES, blank=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'

    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email',]

    objects = UserManager()

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.username
    
    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.name + '' + self.last_name
```

**users > admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import User

# Register your models here.
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = (
        'username',
        'password',
        'email',
        'name',
        'last_name',
        'gender'
    )

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.set_password(obj.password) 
        super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)

admin.site.register(User,UserAdmin)
```

**settings.py**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

te comento que sucede, la primera vez que registras a un usuario desde el admin pones tu contraseña así: qwerty123 y la visualizas así, al momento de darle guardar ejecutas:

```
obj.set_password(obj.password)
```

Si metiste "qwerty123" set_password() lo que hará es hashear el password y guardarlo ya hasheado como: pbkdf2_sha256$216000$ ....

Si entras a editar el usuario, cualquier otro campo, al darle guardar enviaras ahora el password hasheado, no el original y se volverá a hashear en esta parte:

```
obj.set_password(obj.password)
```

Entonces lo que tienes que hacer es validar si el password se cambio o se ingreso para que ejecutes set_password(). Aunque la mejor practica seria crear un modelform para el admin y ahí colocar el método save().

Esto lo puedes ver mas a detalle en la documentación, en este ejemplo:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example